# How to quit pocketsphinx_continuous?

Tags: raspbian-jessie

I recently got my raspberry Pi set up and running Pocketsphinx, however I have run into a slight problem. After inputting the command `pocketsphinx_continuous -adcdev plughw:1` I realized that I did not know how to actually stop pocketsphinx once it had started continuously listening. I looked around and at the various pocketsphinx guides and haven't found a way to stop it.

Escape, CTRL+C, CTRL+X, and `exit`have all failed to shut down the process.

Info:
I am running a Raspberry Pi 3 with a fresh install of Raspbian Jessie

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Not really a Pi specific question.

I'd use the following command to identify the process *name* or *number*

`ps aux | grep pock*`

To kill by its *name*

`sudo killall` *name*

To kill by its *number*

`sudo kill -9` *number*